# Desktop application for macOS to generate components, plugins and modules

Tags: component, development, module, plugin, development-tool

I would like to know if there's a desktop application to easy generate components, plugins and modules for Joomla.

I have tested this two generators:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-joomla3
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-joomla-component

They seem that in some moment in the future will work fine, but for the moment, I only encounted headaches with them.

It exists something, for example, that could work with Netbeans or an IDE like that?

Thanks in advance.